Inherit permissions not working with crontab copy
I have a copy script that runs in a crontab
and I need the folder and files that are copied
to inherit the permissions of the destination directory.
This is the destination folder:
drwxrwxr-x 10 usr1 group1 151 Apr 24 12:47 folder1

When I run the following command, it works as expected
and the test3 folder and files all inherit the permission of "folder1":
/usr/bin/cp -r --no-preserve=mode,ownership /home/usr1/jobs/test3 /s0/folder1/

drwxrwxr-x  3 usr1 group1 54 Apr 24 12:53 test3

When I put the same command into a crontab, the group write permission is not inherited:
#* * * * * /usr/bin/cp -r --no-preserve=mode,ownership /home/usr1/jobs/test2 /s0/folder1/

drwxr-xr-x  3 usr1 group1 54 Apr 24 12:52 test2

Any ideas what is going on?

(1) Why does your crontab line begin with a #? (2) What are the permissions on the source testN directories (in /home/usr1/jobs)?  (3) Have you looked at umask?

(1) Just used # for formatting, otherwise it put a bunch of bullets.  It isn't actually commented out.  (2) drwxrwxr-x 82 usr1 group1 8.0K Apr 24 12:40 jobs   and    drwxrwxr-x  3 usr1 group1 100 Apr 24 12:24 test3 (3) Yes, umask is set to 0002 for this user

Did you ever try this :

tar cfp - /home/usr1/jobs/test3 | ( cd /s0/folder1/;tar xfp -)

reference this .

$ man tar ←  -p, --same-permissions, --preserve-permissions
